# Auto-fill: incrementing one cell but not others

Tags: excel

We all know of the very practical auto-fill option that Excel has. I have encountered a problem where I have 3660 fields in which I want to count their contents. So my formula goes as follows:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A3660;A2)
```

This counts the number of times the value of A2 occurs in the given range. Now if I copy that down to all of the 3660 fields with Excel's auto-fill, the formula increments itself to

```
=COUNTIF(A3:A3661;A3)
```

This is of course not desired. So I tried to have several fields that go like

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A3660;A2)
=COUNTIF(A2:A3660;A3)
...
```

However if I take this range and let it auto-fill, it increments the block like so:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A3660;A2)
=COUNTIF(A2:A3660;A3)
=COUNTIF(A4:A3662;A4)
=COUNTIF(A4:A3662;A5)
...
```

My desire of course is to always have the same range (A2:A3660) and only increment the last value (A2, A3, A4, A5, ...).

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$3660;A2)
```

the $ signs make the formula not increment

Comment: Did not know about this. Thank you.